# Pointer to Array of Bytes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, misra

I'm having some trouble with a pointer declaration that one of my co-workers wants to use because of Misra C requirements.  Misra (Safety Critical guideline) won't let us mere Programmers use pointers, but will let us operate on arrays bytes.  He intends to procur a pointer to an array of bytes (so we don't pass the actual array on the stack.)

```
// This is how I would normally do it
//
void Foo(uint8_t* pu8Buffer, uint16_t u16Len)
{
}

// This is how he has done it
//
void Foo(uint8_t (*pu8Buffer)[], uint16_t u16Len)
{
}
```

The calling function looks something like;

```
void Bar(void)
{
    uint8_t  u8Payload[1024]
    uint16_t u16PayloadLen;

    // ...some code to fill said array...

    Foo(u8Payload, u16PayloadLen);
}
```

But, when pu8Buffer is accessed in Foo(), the array is wrong.  Obviously not passing what it is expecting.  The array is correct in the calling function, but not inside Foo()

I think he has created an array of pointers to bytes, not a pointer to an array of bytes.

Anyone care to clarify? Foo(&u8Payload, u16PayloadLen); doesn't work either.

Comment: Don't arrays always get passed as pointers?

Comment: That is my understanding, but I'm trying to figure out what he is doing, I'm stuck with his implementation.  I need to come up with a good argument to make him change it.

Comment: If it doesn't do what its intended to do, how's `... in Foo(), the array is wrong` for an argument?

Comment: the [] creates one level of indirection and the * another so yes you are one level of indirection off..

Comment: @user1970907: [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*pu8Buffer%29[]) does in fact say that you have a pointer to an array.

Comment: On a more serious note: No pointers? Pass `struct's` and ignore the fact that you copy a lot of unnecessary data here and there.

Comment: @user1970907: how is the array wrong? It's actually perfectly legal to declare a pointer to an array this way. It's rather useless to add the extra indirection (because you have to dereference the pointer to get to the array; best to just rely on array->pointer decay), but it's legal.

Comment: @Jite: oh god passing 1024 bytes by value...that is a bad idea.

Comment: @user1970907 which MISRA rule (rule number?) do you think you are violating when using this function declaration `void Foo(uint8_t* pu8Buffer, uint16_t u16Len) {}` ?

Comment: @nneonneo: Of course it's a bad idea, Sheldon. Iff you can't use pointers however, feel free to present me a better one.

Answer (score 4):

In `void Foo(uint8_t (*pu8Buffer)[], uint16_t u16Len)`, `pu8Buffer` is a pointer to an (incomplete) array of `uint8_t`. `pu8Buffer` has an incomplete type; it is a pointer to an array whose size is unknown. It may not be used in expressions where the size is required (such as pointer arithmetic; `pu8Buffer+1` is not allowed).

Then `*pu8Buffer` is an array whose size is unknown. Since it is an array, it is automatically converted in most situations to a pointer to its first element. Thus, `*pu8Buffer` becomes a pointer to the first `uint8_t` of the array. The type of the converted `*pu8Buffer` is complete; it is a pointer to `uint8_t`, so it may be used in address arithmetic; `*(*pu8Buffer + 1)`, `(*pu8Buffer)[1]`, and `1[*pu8Buffer]` are all valid expressions for the `uint8_t` one beyond `*pu8Buffer`.

Comment: In other words, `uint8_t (*pu8Buffer)[]` decays to `uint8_t * * pu8Buffer`

Comment: @kotlomoy: No, that is not correct. In parameter declarations, identifiers declared as arrays are adjusted to be pointers. However, `uint8_t (*pu8Buffer)[]` does not declare an array; it declares a pointer. And that pointer points to an array, not to a pointer, so it is not a `uint8_t **`. Only the “top level” of the type is considered for adjustment from an array to a pointer; the array aspect of `pu8Buffer` is internal to the type and is not adjusted.

Comment: @kotlomoy the C rule that says that arrays are *adjusted* to pointers in parameter declaration is not recursive: a pointer to an array is not *adjusted*.

Comment: The very same rule he is trying to dodge forbids pointer arithmetic like the one proposed here. The array pointer only confuses things. Instead, use `uint8_t pu8Buffer[]` instead and voila: 100% MISRA-C compliant.

Comment: @Lundin: The question seemed to me a request for explanation of the coworker’s declaration, not a request for alternate code satisfying MISRA.

Answer (score 3):

I take it you are referring to MISRA-C:2004 rule 17.4 (or 2012 rule 18.4). Even someone like me who is a fan of MISRA finds this rule to be complete nonsense. The rationale for the rule is this (MISRA-C:2012 18.4):

> "Array indexing using the array subscript syntax, ptr[expr], is the
>   preferred form of pointer arithmetic because it is often clearer and
>   hence less error prone than pointer manipulation. Any explicitly
>   calculated pointer value has the potential to access unintended or
>   invalid memory addresses. Such behavior is also possible with array
>   indexing, but the subscript syntax may ease the task of manual review.
>
> Pointer arithmetic in C can be confusing to the novice The expression
>   `ptr+1` may be mistakenly interpreted as the addition of 1 to the
>   address held in `ptr`. In fact the new memory address depends on the
>   size in bytes of the pointer's target. This misunderstanding can lead
>   to unexpected behaviour if sizeof is applied incorrectly."

So it all boils down to MISRA worrying about beginner programmers confusing ptr+1 to have the outcome we would have when writing `(uint8_t*)ptr + 1`. The solution, in my opinion, is to educate the novice programmers, rather than to restrict the professional ones (but then if you hire novice programmers to write safety-critical software with MISRA compliance, understanding pointer arithmetic is probably the least of your problems anyhow).

Solve this by writing a permanent deviation from this rule!

---

If you for reasons unknown don't want to deviate, but to make your current code MISRA compliant, simply rewrite the function as

`void Foo(uint8_t pu8Buffer[], uint16_t u16Len)`

and then replace all pointer arithmetic with `pu8Buffer[something]`. Then suddenly the code is 100% MISRA compatible according to the MISRA:2004 exemplar suite. And it is also 100% functionally equivalent to what you already have.

Comment: Agreed, and +1 for the permanent deviation. In many respects, and in my personal opinion only, this rule is almost proof that 100% MISRA compliance is an unachievable pipe-dream.

Comment: Having walked out on a contract where they had used inexperienced, (at MISRA compliance), coders for a aviation project when in response to my suggestion that the coders needed more training to meet the MIRSA requirement of the coding standard was "we will just change the coding standard" I can state categorically that problems like that envisaged are far too common.

Comment: The whole idea with safety standards is to prevent a single inexperienced programmer in a large team from ruining the whole project. The MISRA proposed use of arrays is easier to read and review so less mistakes will be made. I would propose to both educate the programmers and enforce MISRA rules, except where a rule make that particular piece of code less readable.

Comment: @SimonByholm Yes that's overall a sensible approach. Also I think the main intention of this rule is to favour `array[i]` over `*(array + i)` which is quite sound. This is a very old post of mine and I was probably still thinking of MISRA C:2004 which had some weirdly-written rules regarding arrays, corrected in the current MISRA C:2012.