# Passing buffers in C with MISRA compliance

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, misra

MISRA is frustrating our developers.

We are getting MISRA errors about "Do not apply pointer arithmetic to pointer" and "pointer does not point to array".

We are using the syntax of:

```
uint8_t const * p_buffer
```

to pass a buffer to a function that writes the buffer to a SPI bus.

Given an example code fragment:

```
static void Write_Byte_To_SPI_Bus(uint8_t byte);

void Write_Buffer_To_SPI_Bus(uint8_t const * p_buffer,
                             unsigned int quantity)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
  {
    Write_Byte_To_SPI_Bus(*p_buffer++);
  }
}
```

**Is there a way to have a pointer to a cell in an array and increment it that will satisfy MISRA?**

My interpretation is MISRA wants to incrementing indices to the array and not a pointer:

```
void Write_Array_To_SPI_Bus(uint8_t const p_array[],
                            unsigned int quantity)
    {
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
      {
        Write_Byte_To_SPI_Bus(p_array[i]);
      }
    }
```

Many of the developers are old school and prefer to use pointers to `uint8_t` rather than passing an array.

Comment: `p_array` appears to be the wrong type in `void Write_Array_To_SPI_Bus(uint8_t const (*p_array)[], ... Write_Byte_To_SPI_Bus(p_array[i]);`  Did you mean `void Write_Array_To_SPI_Bus(uint8_t const p_array[], `?

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the change.

Comment: Does MISRA permit using indexing on a 'raw' pointer?  If so you can keep the original function declaration and just use `Write_Byte_To_SPI_Bus(p_buffer[i]);`.  I personally find the declaration `uint8_t const (*p_array)[]` to be much less clear than `uint8_t const * p_buffer`. Not that my personal preferences mean anything as far as MISRA compliance is concerned.

Comment: No, can't index off of a raw pointer because indexing can only apply to arrays. :-(

Comment: Do you have a copy of the MISRA guidelines? It goes into detail about each rule, the rationale behind it, and examples of how to work around it. Your second block of code is exactly what the guideline recommends.

Comment: offopic: Is there any online MISRA checker to make some experiments with the code samples provided?

Comment: I'm using one IDE and 2 static analysis that have MISRA checkers and each program has a slightly different interpretation of the MISRA rules. :-(

Comment: To be clear, you're not passing a pointer to an array in the second example, as far as C is concerned there is no difference between `uint8_t const *p` and `uint8_t const p[]` in a function parameter. MISRA has decided to attach semantic meaning to the `[]` syntax. I'm pretty sure the second example is exactly what MISRA wants you to do. Maybe one of your static analysis tools has got it wrong.

Comment: Detail:  "... use pointers to `uint8_t` rather than passing an array." refers to code at the _call_ of `Write_Array_To_SPI_Bus()` in un-posted code.  The warning here refers to `p_buffer++` vs. `p_array[i]` and how `Write_Array_To_SPI_Bus()` received the address.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: The `[]` operator works the same for pointers as well as arrays as far as C is concerned; is MISRA complaining about using `[]` on a pointer type?

Comment: The underlying issue isn't about equality of different methods to access a variable or memory.  MISRA somehow thinks that accessing a buffer element via array indexing is safe than via pointer.  I can understand that a pointer to a byte *is a pointer to a single byte and there are no guarantees that another byte follows it.*

Comment: It is always helpful to annotate with which version of MISRA you are using...  the 2012 edition focusses a number of rules compared with teh 2004 version.

Comment: `*p_buffer++` can be writen as `*p_buffer` and `p_buffer++`. The second part, `p_buffer++`, can be written as(the ugly) `p_buffer = &p_buffer[1];` for strict adherence to MISRA rules.

Comment: If we ignore what MISRA wants, note that the `p_array[i]` version is perhaps faster but certainly never slower to what you had originally. Why use two iterators when you only need one? Also note that your function definition as well as the declaration must be `static` to sate another (far more sound) MISRA rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

John Bode has already given a reply about how (in effect) your second code fragment addresses the MISRA guideline.

I'll address your question "Is there a way to have a pointer to a cell in an array and increment it that will satisfy MISRA?"

The short answer is "no".   Rule 17.4 (in MISRA 2004 - I don't have the 2012 version handy) states "Array indexing shall be the only allowed form of pointer arithmetic".   This is essentially the underpinning of the changes you are required to make in this case.

The longer answer is that the MISRA guidelines are based on a premise that array syntax is somehow safer than pointer dereferencing.  My personal view is that this is a weakness in MISRA, since it doesn't address the problems of an array index going out of bounds - which actually has the same consequence of pointer arithmetic that passes beyond bounds of the array.

Also, the "old school" approach of shadowing a variable (using an index based loop, and incrementing the pointer in the loop) is not exactly good practice either.   It has all the lack of safety that the MISRA guideline is trying to prevent, plus making the code harder to read (mere humans have to work harder to understand that there is a one-to-one relationship between the values of `i` and `p_buffer` - and code which is harder to understand is easier to get wrong).

Answer (score 4):

Remember that as far as C is concerned,

```
void Write_Buffer_To_SPI_Bus(uint8_t const * p_buffer,
                             unsigned int quantity)
```

and

```
void Write_Array_To_SPI_Bus(uint8_t const p_array[],
                            unsigned int quantity)
```

mean *exactly* the same thing; in the context of a function parameter declaration, `uint8_t const * p_buffer` and `uint8_t const p_array[]` both declare *pointer* types, not a pointer and an array type.

Your second snippet should satisfy MISRA, and it's effectively the same as the first snippet.

Comment: The objective isn't about equivalence in C, but how to get past the MISRA checkers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews But your comment "Many of the developers are old school and prefer to use pointers to uint8_t rather than passing an array." suggest that either you and/or your old school people weren't aware of this equivalence. If you incorrectly believed that such code would actually passing a whole array by value, then I can see why you would be upset about MISRA.

Answer (score 0):

> MISRA is frustrating our developers.

To be specific, **a rigid adherence** to MISRA is frustrating your developers.

In the case that you have highlighted, a Deviation is an appropriate mechanism...

Comment: As always, I propose using a [permanent deviation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101587/pointer-to-array-of-bytes/19139759#19139759) against this particular rule.